# Cry you may crook

Tags: riddle

Cry you may crook
As you gaze at my look
A top notch runner
Diverts while I cover
I parch or I perch
But outwardly search
A stretch and a spring
An ingenious thing

## Hint #1

> Lines 1, 3 and 7 relate to its design

## Hint #2

> Lines 4 and 5 relate to its purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cry you may crook
As you gaze at my look

> Umbrella has metal wires/plates/blades which all are crooked.

A top notch runner
Diverts while I cover

> Umbrella diverts anything that falls on it from top.

I parch or I perch
But outwardly search

> Either we see an umbrella opened in the sun or rain or we see it closed and hanging on some support.

A stretch and a spring
An ingenious thing

> An ingenious assembly of a strong waterproof fabric with springs.

Answer:

> It is an Umbrella.

Answer (score 2):

Cry you may crook As you gaze at my look

> Surely policemen have this and crooks are afraid to be hit.

A top notch runner Diverts while I cover

> A crook would change direction to avoid it's firing coverage.

I parch or I perch But outwardly search

> It can cause dehydration (parch). Perch is like holding it on your right hand and using your left hand as a perch for aiming stability.

A stretch and a spring An ingenious thing

> It's long range and springy.

Answer:

> It's a Taser (stun gun)

Comment: Cool, but not the answer

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be:

> **a salmon.**

It's not exactly clear what the answer is, but it very likely has something to do with:

> flowing water, live a river.

*Cry you may crook

As you gaze at my look*

> A crook is a body of flowing water; also, there's the common idiom "cry me a river" that this might refer to. But what are we gazing at?

*A top notch runner

Diverts while I cover*

> Flowing water is sometimes known to be "running" water; when water meets an obstacle, its flow is diverted. But what is covering itself and/or taking cover?

*I parch or I perch

But outwardly search*

> To be parched is to be thirsty, even dried up; a perch is a freshwater fish found in many flowing bodies of water. But what is searching?

*A stretch and a spring

An ingenious thing*

> Again, a spring is another body of flowing water; many geographical formations are called "stretches" when referring to their length or breadth, as in a "stretch of land" or a "stretch of water", the latter being common for rivers and streams.

My answer is because

> **a salmon** is a pink/orange fish that is often admired for its appearance, swims upstream thus diverting water around it, and searches for a place to make its nest when it reaches the uppermost part of the river it is swimming against.

Comment: Aren't you confused with a creek? Or did I just learn a new meaning for crook?

Comment: I think @Jordy is correct, you are thinking of creek. But other than that, a nice answer, but not correct.

Comment: Interesting, I was indeed thinking of some older English where I presumed crook was a body of flowing water. I am familiar with creek, as well, of course. If I had made sure, I probably would have thought my answer differently...

Comment: Oh, maybe it had something to do with "a crooked river", referring to a river-bend. That might explain my mishap.

Comment: There's also a brook, so crook is like a cross between that and creek.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> Gun, probably belonging to a law enforcement official?

Cry you may crook (relates to its design)

> Criminals are / should be afraid of such a gun

As you gaze at my look

> As the criminal looks down the *sight* of the weapon

A top notch runner (relates to its design)

> Bullets go, like, totally fast, y'all

Diverts while I cover (relates to its purpose)

> Covering fire distracts the criminal while the officer finds cover

I parch or I perch (relates to its purpose)

> This one I don't totally get and would appreciate some help. Guns get hot and dry when fired (parch) and you could rest them on things to steady your aim (perch) but that doesn't relate to its purpose.

But outwardly search

> The gun is searching for a target when behind cover

A stretch and a spring (relates to its design)

> The slides moves back and forth on a spring when fired

An ingenious thing

> Firearms are clever designs